# Show more button in a long string removes HTML tags from the string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, append

I found this bug that whenever I tried to use the Read More/Less fucntionality in javascript, the HTML tags in the string removes. I want to retain the HTML tags

```
var maxContentLength = 700;
                            $('.user_comments').each(function() {
                              var text = $(this).text();
                              if (text.length > maxContentLength) {
                                var begin = text.substr(0, maxContentLength);
                                var end = text.substr(maxContentLength);

                                $(this).html(begin)
                                  .append($('<a class="readmore"/>').attr('href', '#more_comment').html(' ...Read More'))
                                  .append($('<span class="hidden_comment" id="more_comment"/>').html(end));
```

This is the code that I am using. Any fix on how I can retain the HTML tags

Comment: Your description of the problem makes very little sense. Can you please edit the question to include all relevant code in a working snippet. I would assume the problem is because you're using `text()`, which ignores all HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read more/ read less description i have a example hopelfully it will helps you alot.
HTML:

```
 <p class="product_description m-0">5.6-ounce, 58/38/4 cotton/poly/spandex jersey with stay-cool wicking technology OGIO heat transfer label for tag-free comfort Self-fabric cadet collar Exposed coil zipper with locking zipper pull Set-in, open hem sleeves Flat matte silicone O heat transfer on back collar Side vents Woven badge with matte silicone O on front left hem Slight drop tail open hem</p>
                                            <div class="readmore">Read more</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product_description
    {
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        display: -webkit-box;
    }
    .readmore,
    .readless
    {
        margin-bottom:30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #4285F4;
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on("click", ".readmore", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).prev().css("display", "block");
                $(this).prev().prev().css("display", "block");
                $(this).removeClass("readmore").addClass("readless").text("Read less");
            });
            $(document).on("click", ".readless", function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).prev().css("display", "-webkit-box");
                $(this).prev().prev().css("display", "-webkit-box");
                $(this).removeClass("readless").addClass("readmore").text("Read more");
            });
```

check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wsmemon/hsera849/) example.